# How to change text via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the "show more" text depending on the state.  This isn't working:

```
        <div id="description">
        text goes here
            </div>
            <div id="more-less-container">
                <a href="#" id="more-less">expand / collapse</a>
            </div>  
            <script>
            var open = false;
            $('#more-less').click(function() {
                if (open) {
                    $('#description').animate({height:'10em'}); 
                    $('#more-less').innerHTML ='show less';             
                }
                else {
                    $('#description').animate({height:'100%'});
                            $('#more-less').innerHTML ='show more'; 
                }
                open = !open;
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$('#more-less').text('show more');` instead of innerHTML.

jQuery wraps DOM Elements into jQuery objects, if you would want to use the `innerHTML` property, you could use the `.html()` function instead - but `.text()` is better as it will html-escape the content.

The alternative, to really access `innerHTML` property, is to get the DOM Element out of the jQuery object, as such: `$('#more-less')[0].innerHTML = 'show more';`.

Comment: I know it was in the original code, but you shouldn't re-select `#more-less` from the DOM. Use `this` instead. `$(this).text()` Especially in the `innerHTML` case where you could just do `this.innerHTML`.

Comment: I didn't notice, but it is very true, `this` in event handlers is the DOM Element on which the event handler was bound.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can use something like

```
$('#more-less').html("show more");
```

or

```
$('#more-less').html("show less");
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
$('#more-less').innerHTML ='show less';
```

Say:

```
$('#more-less').html('show less');
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is a DOM function, for jQuery use .html() since you're manipulating a jQuery object

```
$('#more-less').html('show less');
```